# 引数にthisについて

Tags: java, eclipse

Javaを勉強していますが、thisには2つの使用方法があることがわかります。個人での理解は以下です：
１．同じクラスの別のコンストラクタを呼び出す。
２．メンバー変数名とローカル変数名が競合するときに、メンバー変数を参照するためにはthis キーワードを使います。

で、Appletを勉強する際に以下のコードが出ました：

```
public class EventTest extends Applet implements MouseListener{
  public void init(){
    addMouseListener(this);
  }
}
```

そのthisをaddMouseListenerの引数に代入する意味はなんでしょうか？
なぜthisを代入するのでしょうか？
私はそのページを参照しました：http://www.javadrive.jp/applet/event/index1.html

ご指摘をお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

クラスを利用するには、通常はそのクラスのインスタンスを作成します。
参照サイトの

> EventShori shori = new EventShori();

がそれです。

addMouseListenerメソッドは引数にMouseListenerインターフェースを受け取ります。
上記のEventShoriクラスはMouseListenerインターフェースを実装しているので

> addMouseListener(shori);

とすることができます。
これが「別クラスを用意したい場合」の例です。

そして

> addMouseListener(this);

は、別クラスでなく自分自身(つまりEventTest)のインスタンスを渡しています。
thisは自分自身のインスタンスを表すキーワードになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
分かりやすかった説明です。
先程oracle のdocumentationも見ました。
最初はthisをMouseListenerを指していると思い、どうしても通じなかったので、やはり誤解しました。どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

> そのthisをaddMouseListenerの引数に代入する意味はなんでしょうか？

プログラムの関数の仕様について調べるべきです。

> addMouseListener(this);

関数について知っている前提で説明します。
thisは生成したEventTestです。
addMouseListenerを使用する際にMouseListenerを設定する必要があります。
MouseListenerを型情報として持つ変数を設定する必要があります。
EventTestはインターフェイスとしてMouseListenerが設定されています。

> **検索すべき事項**
>   Java 関数
>   Java インターフェイス

余計なお世話かもしれませんが、Javaの基礎から勉強したほうがよいかと思います。
基礎部分を把握していれば、今回のような疑問は出ないと思います。

Answer (score 0):

addMouseListenerは、マウスイベント（マウスのボタンが押された、離された、マウスが領域に入った、出た）を受け取るオブジェクトを指定するメソッドです。
addMouseListenerの引数は、MouseListenerを実装したクラスのオブジェクトでなければなりません。

質問のコードを見ると
class EventTestは、MouseListenerを実装したクラスになっています。
thisは、EventTestのオブジェクトですから、addMouseListenerの引数として使えます。

このように、クラスのオブジェクトを他のクラスの引数として使い場合にも、thisが使われます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。Fumuさんとuser13314 さんの説明を見るとやっとその意味を理解できました。
どうもありがとうございます。